# When sending message getting SocketException: (Connection Reset, AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am working on a Spring Integration AMQP RabbitMQ project.
I am trying to have the `<rabbit:admin>` create a non-existent queue on an existing topic exchange and bind them with a routing key. Then I am trying to send messages to the queue via console in.

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" 
                 connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
                 exchange="e.products.official" 
                 routing-key="kevin.test.routing.key"
                 queue="q.Kevin.Spring.Rabbit" reply-timeout="100000" />

<rabbit:admin id="rabbitAdmin" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" 
                           host="MyHost"
                           username="MyUserName"
                           password="MyPassword"
                           virtual-host="/nids" 
                           port="5672"/> 

<int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="consoleIn" channel="toRabbit">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="toRabbit" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="toRabbit"
    exchange-name="e.products.official"
    routing-key="kevin.test.routing.key"
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="e.products.official" declared-by="rabbitAdmin" >
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="q.Kevin.Spring.Rabbit" pattern="kevin.test.routing.key" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<rabbit:queue name="q.Kevin.Spring.Rabbit" auto-delete="true" declared-by="rabbitAdmin" />
```

When I run the program everything "goes" but then when I type something in the console and hit "Enter" here is the error I get. I am sure that I am missing something. Could somebody please fill in my blanks for me.
Sorry for the huge stack trace:

```
.........
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:170 - Starting bean 'consoleIn' of type [class org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean]
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'taskScheduler'
2015-02-03 15:55:38 INFO  SourcePollingChannelAdapter:97 - started consoleIn
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG DefaultLifecycleProcessor:179 - Successfully started bean 'consoleIn'
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0'
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:81 - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:81 - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
2015-02-03 15:55:38 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:103 - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
2015-02-03 15:55:39 DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2015-02-03 15:55:40 DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2015-02-03 15:55:41 DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
asdf
2015-02-03 15:55:42 DEBUG SourcePollingChannelAdapter:214 - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=asdf, headers={id=908efc3c-fd13-052c-357b-e3ccba5ef973, timestamp=1423000542576}]
2015-02-03 15:55:42 DEBUG AmqpOutboundEndpoint:72 - org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=asdf, headers={id=908efc3c-fd13-052c-357b-e3ccba5ef973, timestamp=1423000542576}]
2015-02-03 15:55:45 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
2015-02-03 15:55:45 DEBUG LoggingHandler:72 - (inner bean)#77888435 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException, headers={id=10cf2fee-6132-ce5c-6531-db67dfc037ad, timestamp=1423000545683}]
2015-02-03 15:55:45 ERROR LoggingHandler:145 - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:219)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:63)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:441)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:636)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:331)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:376)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:617)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:651)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:203)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534)
    ... 1 more

2015-02-03 15:55:45 DEBUG PublishSubscribeChannel:383 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException, headers={id=10cf2fee-6132-ce5c-6531-db67dfc037ad, timestamp=1423000545683}]
```

Now, I am no expert but I think it has something to do with the admin not being able to declare the queue and bind it to the exchange. I say this because I am able to create an `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` with a queue name and it creates that queue but doesn't bind it to any exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

This implies the server closed the connection for some unknown reason.

If it was a "simple" queue declaration problem, you would see that as the reason for the `ShutdownSignalException`; in this case the cause is a network-level connection reset.

I suggest you look in the server log to see if it provides any more clues as to why the server closed the connection without providing a reason.

**EDIT:**

I just tested with similar configuration to yours, with no issues.

**EDIT#2**:

I was able to get a similar (but slightly different) error by using an invalid `vhost` on the connection factory...

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: No it doesn't. If the server had closed the connection, the `read()` would have got an end of stream, e.g. an `EOFException`, like you got, not `IOException: connection reset` like the OP got.

Comment: Well, his error occurred while reading the repsonse to the amqp connection `start()` so he wasn't yet receiving "messages" per your comment above. `at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)`. This means the connection was opened but some problem happened with the start; the server log may provide some clues as to why the start failed. If not, checkout a wireshark trace.

Comment: The problem ended up being that when the connection was made the `<rabbit:admin>` then began initializing the exchanges, queues, and bindings. The first thing it did was to declare the exchange, which already existed, and which the user did not have permission to do anyway. This caused an exception, causing the initializing process to stop. The software kept running anyway.

The fix was to add `ignore-declaration-exceptions="true"` to the `<rabbit:admin>`.

Comment: Do you all know a way to indicate that I want to bind a queue to an exchange without having to declare the exchange? I would like to be able to have a pre-existing exchange and would like to have the `<rabbit:admin>` create a queue and bind it to that exchange.

Comment: You have to do it "manually" `Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo"); admin.declareBinding(binding);`.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I will need to do some annotated configuration. I was trying to keep it all in one xml file but should work perfectly. Thanks Gary.